# How does 'locale' in Intl-MessageFormat work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization

I'm planning to use `intl-messageformat` for pluralization of texts.

> https://formatjs.io/docs/intl-messageformat/

I'm a bit confused about the second parameter i.e `locale`. At first glance, it seems obvious. However, my question is how does a different `locale` affect the output? For e.g the below snippet will give me a result *You have 1,000 photos.*

```
new IntlMessageFormat(
  `You have {numPhotos, plural,
      =0 {no photos.}
      =1 {one photo.}
      other {# photos.}
    }`,
  'en-US'
).format({numPhotos: 1000})
```

Now if I change the locale to `de` instead of `en-us`, the result remains the same. So what's the significance of this?

Comment: It will not automatically convert. You have to convert it. Check there home page example [here](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/installation). Basically you have to provide all language conversion. Then it will handle when user change language

Comment: @ShubhamVerma In many languages, there might be different rules of pluralization. As it doesn't automatically handle why should we pass the second parameter (`locale`) in here?

Comment: they mentioned in doc.`If you do not provide a locale, the default locale will be used`. So if you want to add translation. You have to manually. This code is from there home example. They add code explicitly in every language. Check out [this](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/tree/main/website/lang)